# How do I visualize an $n$-dimensional function?

Tags: special-functions, graphing-functions

How do I visualize the concept of a function that has more than three dimensions in the context of noise functions?

I understand that a one-dimensional function as a function that can be plotted in a Cartesian plane, [like this](http://natureofcode.com/book/imgs/intro/intro_10.png).

And I understand that a two-dimensional function could be represented in a [grid](http://natureofcode.com/book/imgs/intro/intro_11.png), and a third dimension could represent e.g. a time dimension or a 3-D representation.

But I have trouble understanding the concept of functions with say, six or more, dimensions. I rationally understand the concept that such a function would return values represented by sets of n coordinates, but how do I picture something like that?

Comment: It is not clear what you mean: do you investigate functions that take vectors for variables, or functions that return vectors? In any case, you can't represent them graphically. You may represent their projections, but this might not satisfy you.

Comment: I am asking this question because I am trying to implement noise functions in computer graphics programming. Therefore I' interested in functions that take variables. I am by no means a mathematician, but I believe that in my case it is the projections I'm interested in.

Comment: Let's make it clear: are you asking about functions $: \Bbb R ^n \to \Bbb R$, or $: \Bbb R \to \Bbb R ^n$ or $: \Bbb R ^m \to \Bbb R ^n$?

Comment: I'll try to make myself as clear as possible. If i project a 4-dimensional cube onto a three-dimensional space (Which would be represented by Rm→Rn, is that correct?), then my projection would be [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tesseract). I have a very basic understanding of  Rn spaces in a purely theoretical sense, but when I apply this to generate noise in a Rn space I just have no idea what exactly I am generating. Please excuse my clumsiness regarding mathematics, I'm asking my question on Maths due to the absence of a computer graphics programming alternative.

Comment: *How do I visualize an n-dimensional function ?* - You don't. :-$)$